# insert two SELECT statements into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

hi can some one to tell me how to insert those two select statements into one table.

```
INSERT INTO test(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)

SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC

SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC
```

I have tryed this

```
<?php
include("conf.php");
$query = "INSERT INTO test(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
(SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC )
UNION ALL
(SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC)
";
$data= mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
?>
```

I get this error when i run it

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I also tried with multi query

```
<?php
include("conf.php");
//QUERY 1
$query  = "INSERT INTO test(Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome)
SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC;";
//QUERY 2
$query .= "INSERT INTO test(GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC";

/* execute multi query */
if ($conn->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($conn->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($conn->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$conn->close();
?>
```

When i run this code it inserts the data but the second query inserts also empty rows[image]

**Please some help**

**Last code**

```
<?php
include("conf.php");
$query = "SELECT querya.Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
from 
(SELECT HomeTeam As Team, COUNT(HomeTeam) AS GamesPlayedHome, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedHome, SUM(HomeRedCards) AS RedCardGotHome, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredHome, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY HomeTeam ASC) 
querya inner join 
(SELECT AwayTeam As Team, COUNT(AwayTeam) AS GamesPlayedAway, SUM(AwayGoals) AS GoalsScorredAway, SUM(HomeGoals) AS GoalsAcceptedAway, SUM(AwayRedCards) AS RedCardGotAway, 
SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsScorredAway, SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) AS AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval GROUP BY AwayTeam ORDER BY AwayTeam ASC) 
queryb on querya.Team = queryb.Team";
$data= mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Doing an `INSERT INTO` from a union is how I would do this.  The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the two queries in the union don't return the same number of columns.

Comment: Sow you have any code sugestion

Comment: You know best what the missing column should be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - He's not using union correctly here.  I think he is getting the first half of the columns with the first query and the second half of the columns in the second query and is expecting union to join them together.  He should be looking into joins.  Unless I've read the question horribly wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - thanks but i still cant get it.

Comment: @Twelfth - any code sugestion pls

Comment: @user3255412 - what are the final results that you want look like?  Do you want the away information on the same row as the home information for each team?

Comment: @Twelfth- yes please

Comment: What relationship between home and away teams do you want in your output?

Comment: What is the relationship between home and away teams?  You should be doing a join here I believe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want the away data to be at the same rows as the home

Comment: There is no concept of "same rows" in MySQL.  You must provide an order column or do a join.  This is why you are finding your query impossible to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the data are on the same table can join work

Comment: @user3255412 - can you modify the second query to contain a team column?  If so, you can join query 1 to query 2 on the team name and have them appear on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is psuedo code at best, but it's a try.

```
Select (put all fields in here)
from (put first query in its entirey here) querya
inner join (put second query here, you will need to modify so it has a 'team' column) queryb
on querya.team = queryb.team
```

Get the idea?  Union is the wrong term for what you are trying...Join is what you are looking for.

You had:

```
 "SELECT (Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway)
from ...
```

The brackets aren't needed.

```
 "SELECT Team, GamesPlayedHome, GoalsScorredHome, GoalsAcceptedHome, RedCardGotHome, AvarageGoalsScorredHome, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome, GamesPlayedAway, GoalsScorredAway, GoalsAcceptedAway, RedCardGotAway, AvarageGoalsScorredAway, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
from ...
```

I editted your question, use it from there.

Comment: I tried it and i get this error `Column 'Team' in field list is ambiguous` i add the code at the end of Question

Comment: @user3255412 - you will need to specify which subquery you want to take the value from in your top select statement.  instea of select team, use select querya.team.   You may have to do this with more than one column.

Comment: can you write a sample please

Comment: I did.   Select team should be select querya.team.  I'm not sure how else to sample code that one for you.  It's referred to as qualifying your columns

Comment: i replaced `SELECT (Team, GamesPlayedHome, ...` with `SELECT (querya.Team, GamesPlayedHome, ...` and i now i get this error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: lose the first open bracket.  select querya.team, not select ( querya.team).  Probably will have to get rid of the corresponding close bracket too.

Comment: im sorry man im lost i dont get it ,please can you edit my code Please

Comment: Edited your question, and editted my answer to explain.   select columna,columnb    not select (columna,columnb)

Comment: Oh man thank you for the contribute but still an error `Column 'Team' in field list is ambiguous` im starting to get headache

Comment: Heh, have to put it all together.   select querya.team, etc...    Editted your answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much at least it fuking works, for desert i have one last question can you tell how to implement the `on duplicate key update` here

Comment: Im trying with on `duplicate key update Team = querya.Team, GamesPlayedHome = GamesPlayedHome` im doing it right

Comment: I assume the upvote and check means you got it working.  congrats

Comment: Yes its working but i want also to implement `on duplicate key update`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should 'work' (as in, not error out), but it may not be what you want and/or I may be mistaken...

```
INSERT INTO test
( Team
, GamesPlayedHome
, GoalsScorredHome
, GoalsAcceptedHome
, RedCardGotHome
, AvarageGoalsScorredHome
, AvarageGoalsAcceptedHome
, GamesPlayedAway
, GoalsScorredAway
, GoalsAcceptedAway
, RedCardGotAway
, AvarageGoalsScorredAway
, AvarageGoalsAcceptedAway
)
SELECT HomeTeam 
     , COUNT(HomeTeam)
     , SUM(HomeGoals) 
     , SUM(AwayGoals) 
     , SUM(HomeRedCards) 
     , SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) 
     , SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(HomeTeam) 
  FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval 
 GROUP 
    BY HomeTeam 
 UNION 
   ALL
SELECT COUNT(AwayTeam) 
     , SUM(AwayGoals) 
     , SUM(HomeGoals) 
     , SUM(AwayRedCards) 
     , SUM(HomeGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) 
     , SUM(AwayGoals) / COUNT(AwayTeam) 
  FROM GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndDateInterval 
 GROUP 
    BY AwayTeam
```

(Your spelling is atrocious, BTW)

Comment: i got this error `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Comment: This won't work.  You are only selecting 6 columns but trying to insert 12.  But kudos for finding the missing column, which the OP should have done himself however.